# Accessing an Array Inside JSON with a Postgres Query

Tags: json, postgresql

I have a table with a `data_type` of `json` that I need to query one of the properties inside of it.

This is what the data in the column looks like:

```
{
  "id": 7008,
  "access_links": [
    {
      "product_code": "PRODUCT-1",
      "link": "https://some.url"
    },
    {
      "product_code": "PRODUCT-2",
      "link": "https://someOther.url"
    }
  ],
  "library_id": "2d1203db-75b3-43a5-947c-8555b48371db"
}
```

**I need to be able to pull out and filter by the `product_code` nested inside of the `access_links`.**

I can get one layer deep by using this query:

```sql
SELECT
    courses.course_metadata -> 'access_links' as access_links 
FROM
    courses
```

This seems to get me into the column, but I can't query any further.

The output I receive from the query looks like:

```
[{"product_code":"PRODUCT-1","link":"https://some.url"},{"product_code":"PRODUCT-2","link":"https://someOther.url"}]
```

I've tried using the `->>` and `#>>` operators, but they both complain about the array not starting with a `{`. Also worth noting that the column is a data type of `JSON` not `JSONB`, so the `@>` operator doesn't work.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help?

```
select 
json_array_elements (x->'access_links')->'product_code' as product_code
from 
(select '{
  "id": 7008,
  "access_links": [
    {
      "product_code": "PRODUCT-1",
      "link": "https://some.url"
    },
    {
      "product_code": "PRODUCT-2",
      "link": "https://someOther.url"
    }
  ],
  "library_id": "2d1203db-75b3-43a5-947c-8555b48371db"
}'::json x 
  )  as v 
  ;
```

### product_code

"PRODUCT-1"
 "PRODUCT-2"

Comment: Perfect! That was exactly what I needed. I had seen the `json_array_elements`, but couldn't find a use case that fit what I was trying to do.